# Android 5.0: Recolor status bar icons

Tags: android, android-theme

In my app, I am animating the status bar color between a dark blue color and white using `Window.setStatusBarColor()`. The icons in the status bar are initially white, like they should be. However, when I animate the background color to white, the icons stay white, making the contents of the status bar invisible. Is there a way to tell the system to recolor the things in the status bar to black?